# Demonstration Gradient Descent

Tags: derivatives, optimization, machine-learning, gradient-descent

The directional derivative represents the slope of a function along a direction. The minimization of the directional derivative is equal to the anti-gradient, and the proof of this is clear to me. But why is the minimization of the directional derivative at a point x, equivalent to finding the direction where the function at point x decreases faster? I can't understand why the anti-gradient gives direction and direction in which the function decreases faster. What is the relationship between the minimization of the directional derivative and the monotony of a function to be minimized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is rooted in the relation between derivatives and linear approximations by tangents. When you take a differentiable real-valued function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, a linear approximation of $f$ at a point $a = (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ could be defined by:

$$g(x) = f(a) + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f_{x_i}(a)(x_i-a_i)$$
where $x = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

It is easy to verify that $g(a) = f(a)$ and $\nabla g = \nabla f$.

Now, take any unit vector $\hat{u}$, if we want to minimize $D_{\hat{u}}f(a)$, we have to minimize $\nabla f(a) \cdot \hat{u} = \nabla g(a) \cdot \hat{u}$. So we could look at the function $g$ instead of $f$.

For the cases of the first and second dimensions where the graph of $g$ is a line and a plane respectively, it is easy to imagine that the direction which minimizes the directional derivative is in the opposite direction of the gradient.

In higher dimensions, it becomes more difficult to see the relationship. Let's look for a unit vector $\hat{u} = (u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n)$ such that $g(a + \hat{u})$ is minimized.

$$g(a + \hat{u}) = f(a) + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f_{x_i}(a)((a_i + u_i)-a_i) = f(a) + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f_{x_i}(a) u_i = f(a) + \nabla g(a) \cdot \hat{u}$$

Since $f(a)$ is a constant, then we need to minimize the term $\nabla g(a) \cdot \hat{u}$. It could be easily verified that the minimum of the term occurs when $\hat{u} = - \frac{\nabla g(a)}{\| \nabla g(a)\|}$. In other words, when $\hat{u}$ is in the opposite direction of the gradient.

However, this is not true for minimizing $f(a + \hat{u})$. At the first glance, one might think that to minimize $f(a + \hat{u})$, the unit vector $\hat{u}$ must be in the opposite direction of the gradient. But the length of the vector $\hat{u}$ is 1 which is large enough for the function to have many local minima in the unit disc around $a$ so that no single direction is optimal.

This confusion in the meaning of "steepest descent" or "fast decreasing" makes one think incorrectly of gradient descent. The direction of the "steepest descent" should only be understood "infinitesimally" and not with a distance away from a point. It should be noted that the opposite direction of the gradient may not be the best direction to find an absolute minimum or even a good local minimum after going through several iterations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, it is now clearer to me. But I have two last questions about your answer:

1. So the concept behind the Gradient Descent was discovered, starting from the approximation of the function with (the hyperplane) tangent. But why is it initially assumed to approximate the function and then find the direction that allows the performed approximation to decrease faster? What I'm wondering is whether there is some conceptual reason for this, or is it just the result of mathematical steps to lead back to minimising the directional derivative?

Comment: 2. So the descent of the gradient always allows us to find a stationary point, and so we may not necessarily have a local minimum in output, but we may also have a local maximum, have I understood correctly? This is because at each step the algorithm moves towards the direction of maximum descent, but the descent could also lead us to a local maximum (if for example we have started incorrectly from around the global maximum (if it exists))? Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: @FrancescoLadogana Your welcome. regarding your second comment, yes you could either reach a local maximum (not a minimum) or a stationary point and not necessarily a local minimum,

Comment: @FrancescoLadogana Regarding your first comment, the reason behind starting from the tangent hyperplane is because the derivative is related to it "infinimitesimally" around the desired point. So, intuitively speaking, what can be said about the derivative is also what could be said about the tangent hyperplane within a neighborhood around the point that gets smaller and smaller as it approaches the point. Think of it as different faces of the same coin.

Comment: Okay, i understanding, thank for all, you were very clear!!

Comment: And what I forgot to mention is that you could also conclude that the direction in which $g(a + \vec{u})$ is minimal for any vector (not only unit vectors) always has the direction opposite to the gradient. Whatever the magnitude of the vector. So as the magnitude approaches zero, the best direction to minimize $g$ is always opposite to the direction of the gradient. So infinimitesimally speaking, the fastest decreasing direction of $f$ is the opposite direction to the gradient.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!